# How to use OpenShift's port-forward with WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, openshift

Their [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/) seems a bit outdated. I couldn't log in my local application through the wp-admin panel, even though my wp-config is pointing to (what I think to be) the right port.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why would you need to use port-forwarding with your wordpress installation?

Comment: Hi @corey112358! Because I've a local installation of WordPress and I'd like to use my database stored on OpenShift. So, I think I should use port-forwarding, right? Or there is any other technique I should use instead?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your wp-config.php file with the remote connection information?  And what shows up when you do the rhc port-forward.

Comment: I'm not sure which part are you interested in... because this file contains authentication information such as the name of the db, host, user and password. I've taken this info from my openshift dashboard...